# How do I copy vendors from previous release when deploying Symfony2 with Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby, symfony, capistrano3

I have recently changed from Capifony to Capistrano 3. I have the following in my deply.rb but it seems to take a long time to install the vendors. My old Capifony script copied the vendors from the previous release before updating them. Is there a way to do this with Capistrano 3?

```
namespace :composer do
    before 'install', 'change_dir'
    desc 'Composer update'
    task :change_dir do
        on roles(:app) do
            execute "cd #{release_path}/ && composer update"
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that but it appears to copy the contents of the previous vendor and put them in the latest release in a vendor subfolder: /usr/bin/env cp -R /var/www/releases/20141107085828/vendor /var/www/releases/20141107093505/vendor So I end up with /var/www/releases/20141107093505/vendor/vendor/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [capistrano-copy-files](https://github.com/peterjmit/capistrano-copy-files) extension for Capistrano. [Here](https://github.com/capistrano/composer/pull/9#) is discussion why it's not added to Composer extension. In example bellow I'm just guessing, because I still use capifony or capistrano 2 for PHP projects.

```
set :copy_files, ['vendor']
```